# Differences between RF transceiver modules

Tags: pcb, rf, lora

I want to add a wireless M-BUS to the PCB I designed, but they are very expensive (about $30). While researching wireless M-BUS modules, a question came to my mind.

When I look at the datasheet of the [Metis-I](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/w%C3%BCrth-elektronik/2605041183000/9593518)  module, it says M-BUS and the RF standard General ISM < 1 GHz. But it's expensive for me.

So can I use a LoRa module with the same RF standard? Data is transferred from SPI or UART, and send via an antenna. Don't they both work the same way? What are the differences between different RF transceiver modules? Do LoRa and wireless M-BUS work differently?

If I pay attention to the features, like frequency, RF standard, output power, etc. can I use a module that does not mention M-BUS in its datasheet?

Comment: `Do LoRa and wireless M-BUS work differently?` ... what did your research determine

Comment: When you are paying attention to RF standards, what are you paying attention to if LoRA and M-BUS don't qualify as RF standards to you?

Comment: @DKNguyen LoRa and M-BUS modules with RF standard General ISM < 1 GHz are available. Protocols are different. I'm trying to learn but the modules seem to work the same way

Comment: Not all Lora modules are the same. Some may have just the radio chip and others might have the radio and microcontroller chip.  If in doubt, find a module that has Arduino support as this means it is probably popular and has wide support. ISM band < 1GHz is not a standard. It could be 433MHz, 868MHz and so on and depending on which country you are in as to what is legal. For point of comparison, the M1 module looks like it uses 868MHz and has the microcontroller and radio chip.

Comment: @Kartman I don't really see how it would be possible to use Lora on common sub GHz bands, because it's spread spectrum and bands like 433MHz (Europe) are in practice restricted to 1mW ERP for wideband radios. Either the range would be crap or it wouldn't pass CE marking.

Comment: (I have evaluated LoRA modules for 433MHz so they exist, but the manufacturer couldn't manage to tell me how to legally use that product in practice.)

Comment: @Lundin, supposedly you can run more than 0dBm EIRP at 868MHz but you have a limited tx duty cycle.